# Map a network location to a shared OneDrive folder

Tags: onedrive-for-business

My (small) client uses Office 365 and has shared a folder from her OneDrive with me - using my Microsoft account, i.e. I **don't** have an account on their Office 365 system. Works a treat with Office documents in that Word can browse this shared folder directly. However, not many apps are "OneDrive/SharePoint" friendly specifically LibreOffice which we use extensively for it's drawing app.

I'm familiar enough with SharePoint with other clients whereby I **do** have an account on their Office 365 system in that you can add network locations to SharePoint document libraries. Not without it's problems but it does work.

I wondered if you can do the same with a OneDrive folder shared in this way? The path used in Office looks like this:

https://myclient-my.sharepoint.com/personal/fred_bloggs_myclientdomain/Documents/Documents/IT%20and%20computers/Projects/Caravan%20site%20Wi-Fi

This won't map as a network location. I'm going to guess this is because you can't access OneDrive shared in this way via WebDAV?

Comment: When you navigate there, is there not a "Sync" button? That will create a location on your computer that syncrhonises the drive, a bit like a network shared drive, but rather it's a real folder that's managed by OneDrive for Business.